# Characters not placed in the expected position on Linux terminal when printed using C++

Tags: c++, linux

I'm building a simple terminal application for Linux-based operating systems. It is a simple system fetch application that is supposed to print some system info in the terminal and I'd like the information to be enclosed within a rectangular box.

To achieve that for now I'm doing something like this:

```
vector<string> fetch{}; // Declaring string vector that will hold the system info
const int rm{88}; // Characters to remove when computing paddings
fetch.push_back("╭─────────────────── System info ───────────────────╮");

// Define paddings
int total_len = fetch[0].length();
int model_pad = total_len - model().length() - rm;

fetch.push_back("│" + model() + string(model_pad, ' ') + "│"); // Add info about model to the vector
```

The `model()` function returns a string with the name of the computer model. These are just some example lines, but in general I added all the system info to the vector and printed everything out with a for loop.

The idea for each line, is to add as many white spaces after the system info as needed to fill the remaining space between the length of the current info and the general length of the box, so I can put a vertical line at the end at the correct location.
However, as you may notice, I needed to declare another variable `rm` holding some arbitrary integer value that get subtracted from the original "whitespace" length because without it the vertical bars at the end would be placed far after the position they were supposed to be.

This behavour seems to be consistent across different terminal emulators and I can't figure out why this is happening (if you are wondering, I found the right `rm` value with trials and errors).

I know that in general the code might not be optimal but I'd like to know why this weird behaviour is happening.

Edit:

- Operating system: Manjaro Linux
- Compiler: g++ 12.2.1

Comment: Because you use Unicode characters in UTF-8 encoding and `total_len = fetch[0].length()` is not a string length in characters but is a length in bytes (number of `char`).

Comment: Try `std::cout << std::string("│").length() << '\n';` and you'll get the point.

Comment: Your string size calculation needs to count Unicode **graphemes** (Unicode characters), not UTF-8 **bytes** for correct positioning on your Linux terminal.

Comment: Or just use ncurses or some other TUI library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::string` is not a string of characters, it's a string of bytes. Its `length()` function is not counting characters, it's counting bytes. And those line-drawing characters that you are using are *probably* taking up more than one byte each, but without further details about platform and compiler it's impossible to be certain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for the missing information but I just started to learn C++ so I wasn't sure about what info are necessary. Gonna add those info in the post.